Why is the result of calculating definite integrals in this way incorrect
let $$t=\cos x$$
then
$$
\int_{-1}^1{\mathrm{arc}\sin \sqrt{1-t^2}}\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^{\pi}{x\sin x}\mathrm{d}x=\pi 
$$
Why is it wrong?
The correct result is
$$
\int_{-1}^1{\mathrm{arc}\sin \sqrt{1-t^2}}\mathrm{d}t=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x\sin x}\mathrm{d}x=2
$$

Because the first approach implicitly uses the fact that we always have$$\arcsin(\sin x)=x\label{a}.\tag1$$when $x\in[0,\pi]$. But this is not true. We actually do have \eqref{a} when $x\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$. But, when $x\in\left[\frac\pi2,\pi\right]$, we have $\arcsin(\sin x)=\pi-x$ instead.

(+1) Side remark: $\int_0^1\arcsin\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$, interpreted as an "area under the curve", can also be directly rewritten as, so to speak, the "area left to the curve": $\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos ydy$.
